# Writing a linq Query to add elements with duplicate IDs together

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm attempting to convert some sql I have to some linq, and having some trouble.

I have a table with 3 columns that we'll call MfrID, CatID, and Count.

I want to be able to give some method a list of CatIDs and it will go through the table, and find all the MfrIDs and Counts that contain a CatID in that list, and add the counts together where the mfrIDs are equal then order the table by the the new TotalCounts and then return the top X results.

I feel this is best explained in code, here is a sample test i'm trying to work out

```
     [TestMethod]
    public void tempFiguringOutLinqQuery()
    {
        //some example data of what a sql table could look like
        var sampleData = new []
            {
                new {MfrId = 1, CatId = 1, MfrCount = 3},
                new {MfrId = 1, CatId = 2, MfrCount = 1},
                new {MfrId = 5, CatId = 1, MfrCount = 2},
                new {MfrId = 5, CatId = 6, MfrCount = 20},
                new {MfrId = 3, CatId = 5, MfrCount = 14},
                new {MfrId = 3, CatId = 2, MfrCount = 7},
                new {MfrId = 3, CatId = 1, MfrCount = 9},
                new {MfrId = 2, CatId = 1, MfrCount = 1}
            }.ToList();

        var catList = new List<int> {1, 2};

        //where CatIDList.Contains(1 or 2), Add MfrCount where MfrIds are equal, then take the top 3 results ordered by mfrCountDescending
        //ughhhhh
        var results = sampleData.Where(w => catList.Contains(w.CatId)).GroupBy(g => g.MfrCount); 

        //expected results
        // { MfrId = 3, MfrCount = 16 }
        // { MfrId = 1, MfrCount = 4 }
        // { MfrId = 5, MfrCount = 2 }
        Assert.Inconclusive();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to group by the manufacturer ID, then apply a transformation to each group. You were *nearly* there, just grouping by the wrong field and missing the transformation. For example, including the sorting and "taking the top 3" we'd get:

```
var results = sampleData.Where(w => catList.Contains(w.CatId))
                        .GroupBy(w => w.MfrId) // Not MfrCount!
                        .Select(g => new { MfrId = g.Key,
                                           MfrCount = g.Sum(x => x.MfrCount) })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.MfrCount)
                        .Take(3);
```

There's an overload of `GroupBy` which actually takes a group projection anyway, but personally I find it simpler to read the version with the `Select` separated out.

Answer (score 1):

Group filtered data by `MfrId` (that will be group key) and calculate sum of `MfrCount` for each group:

```
var query = from d in sampleData
            where catList.Contains(d.CatId)
            group d by d.MfrId into g
            select new {
               MfrId = g.Key,
               MfrCount = g.Sum(x => x.MfrCount)
            };

var result = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.MfrCount).Take(3);
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var result = sampleData.Where(d => catList.Contains(d.CatId))
                       .GroupBy(d => d.MfrId)
                       .Select(g => new {
                           MfrId = g.Key,
                           MfrCount = g.Sum(x => x.MfrCount)
                       })
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.MfrCount)
                       .Take(3);
```

Result:

```
{ MfrId = 3, MfrCount = 16 }
{ MfrId = 1, MfrCount = 4 }
{ MfrId = 5, MfrCount = 2 }
```

EDIT: Missed that you need only top 3 results, added `Take(3)` to queries.